# Using a core Joomla component as a base for a custom component

Tags: php, web, joomla

I'm attmpting to pull all the necessary files that make up the **Weblinks** core componnent out of my **Joomla 2.5** installation into a separate directory so that I can use it to make a custom component with additional fields.

My problems are:

1. I can't seem to figure out all the files needed to be pulled out in order to then successfull re-install the custom component
2. I can't seem to figure out all the renaming that needs to be done in the custom component in order to ensure it doesn't corrupt the core installation when I re-install it.

Has anyone done this before? I looked at creating a custom component from scratch and it seems like far too much workfor a non web developer. This also seems overkill in order to add a couple of fields.

Comment: I'd recommend using something like the free version of this to get an installable file: http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/. Then customize it with code from the core component. Getting everything named right can be pretty tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a clean copy (off-root) of the component's folder structure as required by the component's manifest file (the xml in the administrator/components/com_weblinks).

This should be installable and complete to start with.

Now issue the following commands if you're on Linux or OSX; or download cygwin if you're on windows

```
grep -rl oldname . |xargs sed -i -e 's/oldname/newname/g'
grep -rl Oldname . |xargs sed -i -e 's/Oldname/Newname/g'
grep -rl OLDNAME . |xargs sed -i -e 's/OLDNAME/NEWNAME/g'
rename 's/oldname/newname/g' *
```

Make sure you renamed all occurences:

```
grep -rli oldname .
```

If nothing comes up, you're good to go; else, simply grep and pipe to sed as shown above. Make sure you never use case-insensitive replacements: that would definitely break your code.

Proofread the .xml manifest manually.

Repackage, and try installing. Read any error messages (or the error log if it's not clear), you should have little to no problems making an installable package). Installing repeatedly does not cause damage (unless you make naming mistakes in the .xml files).

P.S.: This answers your question, but maybe @David-Frisch's suggestion could be easier and more effective in your case, you get all the component structure set up in a neat and simple style, with little redundancy in the frontend editing features, but overall a great start. They moved to a [new site](http://www.component-creator.com).

Comment: I think this path is definitely the way I want to go, but I may have accepted prematurely. I'm having trouble with view not found errors now: `View not found [name, type, prefix]: c4meweblinks, html, c4meweblinksView`. Any idea? I've looked at the Joomla docs on naming convention and it all seems good.

Comment: Although I never verified this, it has been pointed out that numbers in the view names cause issues (rename c4me to cforme); other than that, the view name must correspond to its folder and component but I guess you got that right.

Comment: Turns out this was more to do with a quirk in the core weblinks component. The component presumes that your plural admin view will be same name as the component. Dooing `JFactory::getApplication()->input->set('view', $view);` before calling `parent::display();` in the controller fixed it. I guess it was never intended for customising.

Answer (score 1):

You can create new component easily by using joomla's Official [tutorials](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component).

First you have to identify you requirement like your component required Front end and back end or sql tables etc.

The next step is to identify you requirement matching Joomla official tutorials That you can easily get from Articles in this series section.

At the end of that tutorial you can download a `com_helloworld` component.

Just unzip the package and rename all the occurrence of `hellowolrd` from the folder structure if you are using an IDE like Dreamweaver simply achieve this by using folder search options.

This will rename you complete `com_helloworld` folder contained `helloword` text .

The final step is to rename your files all the occurrence of your helloworld in your file you have set to new name of your component. and the folder too

Then zip the package and task completed.!

Hope this make sense..